# Using Rollup in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble using rollup in mysql. I want a table that looks something like this:

Person | Count

John   |   3

Sam    |   2

Total  |   5

The code I wrote:

```
SELECT person, count(*), IFNULL(count(*),"Total") AS Count FROM ProductsSold GROUP BY 
person WITH ROLLUP;
```

But Instead total is staying null and all my counts say BLOB in workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you want to rename the person `NULL` which holds the `ROLLUP` result to `Total`. That means you have do your `IFNULL` construct on the `person` column:

```
SELECT IFNULL(person,"Total") as person, count(*) AS Count
FROM ProductsSold 
GROUP BY person WITH ROLLUP
```

makes:

```
John   3
Sam    2
Total  5
```